# Hibernate Can not insert joined table

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, model-view-controller

I am working on hibernate. I have two entities: Project and Contact. These two entities have a one-to-many relationship. But, when I save a Project class, hibernate does not insert any record in Contact table(class) and just updates the Project table.

The business is;

There are lots of Projects. User select a project with double click which opens new jsp(got project id on that) and entering contact info and push Add button. What I am trying to do is the project that user selected is on db already. There is ok but I want to insert contact table with my contact info which include project_id. I am expecting from hibernate is update project table also insert contact table. But now reality is just updating project table only.

Here is structure of my classes: the main controller is Contact Controller.

#### Project.java:

```
package Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="xxer_Projects_t")
public class Project {



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private int project_id;

    @Column(name = "Project_number")
    private String Project_number;

    @Column(name = "Project_name")
    private String Project_name;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,
                         CascadeType.MERGE,
                         CascadeType.DETACH,
                         CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "constructor_id")
    private Constructor constructor;


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "project",
             cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,
             CascadeType.MERGE,
             CascadeType.DETACH,
             CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private List<Contact> contacts;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "project",
             cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,
             CascadeType.MERGE,
             CascadeType.DETACH,
             CascadeType.REFRESH})
    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "project",
             cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,
             CascadeType.MERGE,
             CascadeType.DETACH,
             CascadeType.REFRESH})
    public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }


    public Project() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public Project(String project_number, String project_name) {
        Project_number = project_number;
        Project_name = project_name;
    }


    public int getProject_id() {
        return project_id;
    }


    public void setProject_id(int project_id) {
        this.project_id = project_id;
    }


    public String getProject_number() {
        return Project_number;
    }


    public void setProject_number(String project_number) {
        Project_number = project_number;
    }


    public String getProject_name() {
        return Project_name;
    }


    public void setProject_name(String project_name) {
        Project_name = project_name;
    }


    public Constructor getConstructor() {
        return constructor;
    }


    public void setConstructor(Constructor constructor) {
        this.constructor = constructor;
    }



}
```

#### Contact.java:

```
package Model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="xxer_contacts_t")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private int id;
    private String name_surname;
    private String email;
    private String phone;




    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,
             CascadeType.MERGE,
             CascadeType.DETACH,
             CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;




    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }




    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }




    public String getName_surname() {
        return name_surname;
    }




    public void setName_surname(String name_surname) {
        this.name_surname = name_surname;
    }




    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }




    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }




    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }




    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }




    public Project getProject_id() {
        return project;
    }




    public void setProject_id(Project project_id) {
        this.project = project_id;
    }




    public Contact() {


    }

}
```

#### ContactController.java:

```
package Controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import Dao.ConstructorDao;
import Dao.ContactDao;
import Dao.ProjectDao;
import Model.Constructor;
import Model.Contact;
import Model.Project;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ContactController
 */
@WebServlet("/ContactController")
public class ContactController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ContactController() {
        super();


    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        int projectid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));





        if (request.getParameter("Operation").equals("add")) {
            String name =  request.getParameter("NameSurname");
            String email =  request.getParameter("Email");  
            String phone =  request.getParameter("Phone");


            Project p = ProjectDao.getProjectById (projectid);

            List <Contact> loc = new ArrayList<>();

            Contact cont = new Contact();

            cont.setName_surname(name);
            cont.setEmail(email);
            cont.setPhone(phone);
            cont.setProject_id(p);

            loc.add(cont);

            p.setContacts(loc);

            ProjectDao.insert(p);
            /*
            cont.setName_surname(name);
            cont.setEmail(email);
            cont.setPhone(phone);
            cont.setProject_id(p);


            ContactDao.Insert(cont);
            */

            }

            // List 



            List<Contact> ListOfContacts =ContactDao.getListofContacts(projectid);

            request.setAttribute("ListOfContacts", ListOfContacts);
            request.setAttribute("id", projectid);


        RequestDispatcher dispacher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/ProjectContacts.jsp");
        dispacher.forward(request, response);


    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

#### ProjectDao.java:

```
package Dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import Model.Constructor;
import Model.OfferType;
import Model.Project;
import _JSP.HibernateUtil;

public class ProjectDao {

    public ProjectDao() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


/*

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int id = 1;

        Project p = new Project ("Proje3","TRIA Projesi");

        insert(p);

    }

    */

    public static void insert(Project p) {

        SessionFactory sf =HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

        //SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();



        Session session = sf.openSession();
        try {
        session.beginTransaction();



        //Constructor con = session.get(Constructor.class, consid);
        //p.setConstructor(con);


        //session.save(p);
        //session.persist(p);

        session.saveOrUpdate(p);

        session.getTransaction().commit();


        }
        finally {

            session.close();
            System.out.println("Project Session Closed!!!!");
        }




    }

public static List<Project> getListofProjects() {


        //SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        SessionFactory sf =HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

        Session session = sf.openSession();


        //List <OfferType> ol  = session.createCriteria(OfferType.class).list();



        List <Project> ol =session.createQuery("from Project order by 1 desc").list();  

        session.close();

        return ol;


    }


public static Project getProjectById(int id) {


    SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = sf.openSession();


    //List <OfferType> ol  = session.createCriteria(OfferType.class).list();



    Project p =session.get(Project.class,id);

    session.close();

    return p;


}

        public static List<Constructor> LoadConsDropDown() {

        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sf.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();


        List <Constructor> listofcons = new ArrayList<Constructor>();
        listofcons = session.createQuery("from Constructor order by name asc").list();





        session.close();

        return listofcons;


    }

}
```

#### ContactDao.java:

```
package Dao;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import Model.Contact;
import Model.Project;
import _JSP.HibernateUtil;

public class ContactDao {

    public ContactDao() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


public static void Insert(Contact c) throws SQLException {

        //SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    SessionFactory sf =HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();   

    Session session = sf.openSession();

    try {   
        session.beginTransaction();


        //Constructor con = session.get(Constructor.class, consid);
        //p.setConstructor(con);


        session.save(c);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

    finally {

        session.close();
        System.out.println("Contact Session Closed!!!!");

    }



    }



public static List<Contact> getListofContacts(int id) {


        //SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        SessionFactory sf =HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

        Session session = sf.openSession();


        //List <OfferType> ol  = session.createCriteria(OfferType.class).list();



        //List <Contact> ol =session.createCriteria(Contact.class).list();


        List <Contact> ol = session.createCriteria(Contact.class).createAlias("project", "p").add(Restrictions.eq("p.project_id", id)).list();



            session.close();


        return ol;  


    }

}
```

Comment: Which method is calling when you are saving the Contacts Page. In that method ,you need  to create new Contact() Object (if it has 3 contacts, then 3 contact objects) and set the contact values to that object and add it to "contacts" List and the save the Projects entity.

Comment: @KishoreKumar actually every time i add one contact with get method. As you can see on contact controller i am creating Contact object and adding list.